# No data relationships in big table databases?

Tags: nosql, bigdata, bigtable, column-family

> If the relationships between the data are as important as the data
> itself (such as distance or path calculations), then don't use a
> column family/big table database.
>
> (Quoted from article [Big data woes: Which database should I use?](http://features.techworld.com/data-centre/3373754/big-data-woes-which-database-should-i-use/) by Andrew Oliver)

Could someone elaborate on what Andrew meant by this? It is not entirely evident to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big data usually means that databases are distributed on multiple servers. Table-based database usually have severe scaling problems when you need to join entries with each other which are on different servers. That makes them unsuitable for use-cases which focus on connections between database entries. Their query languages are also often not very well-equipped for analyzing connections.

In that case you should consider using a graph database like Neo4j. The pros and cons of graph databases are described further below in the article you quoted.

> Common uses for graph databases include geospatial problems,
>   recommendation engines, network/cloud analysis, and bioinformatics --
>   basically, **anywhere that the relationship between the data is just as
>   important as the data itself**.

Graph databases make it easy to follow relationships between database entries. They make it easy to query for things like the friends of the friends of a user or all users with common interests.